# Creating a cube animating their faces

Tags: adobe-after-effects

As a beginner, I'm not sure how to create rectangles that form a cube so I can get something like shown below:

[image]

I created angled rectangles in another application and tried to create an idea to show, but I'd really like to use the elements that After Effects provides.

[image]

I would also like to know how to control the quality of the corners of the elements created within After Effects.

[image]

Anyone willing to help?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use shape layers.

Here's a short video that should give you all you need:

https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/ImpossibleTanAmericancurl

Now you basically need to move three rectangles to the right position and animate the scale property.

Comment: I hope it's big enough to see. This was the only way I could upload the clip.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Illustrator first it can help you have a little more control of your art. So, I suggest make all your assets first in Ai first and then import them in After Effects. Then perform the scaling and add keyframes to match your animated example. Although, for something this simple you could probably also do it in Premier Pro.

If you don't know any of that stuff you need to stop what you're doing and first lookup how to use the basics of After Effects and Illustrator and then follow a tutorial the explains how to import and use the assets you created. Then research key framing. That way it will be a lot easier for you.

Things to consider: You can indeed use the tools in Ae to make the artwork. I don't recommend that though because Ae isn't really an Illustration tool. Some people have no problem doing it all in Ae.